# Resolving DNS through HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: dns, http, https, tunneling, dnscrypt

Is there a way to resolve DNS through HTTP/HTTPS, the case was:

my ISP redirecting every DNS request to their own DNS and poisoning the DNS records.

all I need is a software that could resolve requests using http or https, for example, when I set /etc/resolv.conf to

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

there would be a program/service that listens to 127.0.0.1:53 and submit HTTP requests containing DNS queries to another server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found alternative answer that could solve the problem, using encrypted DNS, first install:

```
pacman -Sy dnscrypt-proxy
```

Then start the [dnscrpyt](http://dnscrypt.org/) program manually:

```
dnscrypt-proxy --resolver-name=cloudns-can
```

The list could be found on `/usr/share/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv`

Or automatically:

```
sudo systemctl enable dnscrypt-proxy
sudo systemctl start dnscrypt-proxy
```

Then change your `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Similar, but using SysV init  and BIND http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270716/configure-bind-as-forwarder-only-no-root-hints-encrypted-rpz-blacklist-wh

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you consider DNSSEC and diffrent DNS resolver?
You can get a list from here:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Public+DNS+Servers&t=ffsb&ia=answer&iax=1