# resolving DNS via Tor

Tags: dns, bind, dnsmasq, tor

When I am using Tor, and not using the Tor bundle there is a possibility of DNS leaks in certain situations.

What can be done to minimize it? Is it possible to resolve DNS via Tor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To minimize DNS leaks, it is indeed possible to resolve DNS via Tor.

For that, add to your `/etc/tor/torrc` the line:

```
DNSPort 9053
```

And restart the `tor` service with:

```
service tor restart
```

To test it out, do:

```
$nslookup
set port=9053
server 127.0.0.1
www.cnn.com
```

If using resolvconf/dnsmasq, change your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
 no-resolv
 server=127.0.0.1#9053
 listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

If simply using `/etc/resolv.conf` that is not changed by a DHCP configuration, change `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1#9053
```

or in `BIND` place in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
options {
    forwarders {
        127.0.0.1 port 9053;
    }
}
```

Using a reputable `dnscrypt` service is in principle more secure  than leaving your DNS resolution up to some element in the chain of the Tor network; see [Configure BIND as Forwarder only (no root hints), encrypted + RPZ blacklist / whitelist all together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270716/configure-bind-as-forwarder-only-no-root-hints-encrypted-rpz-blacklist-wh).

Also take note that resolving DNS via a Tor gateway is notably slower, and it is strongly advised to have a local cache such as `dnsmasq` or `BIND`.

I will leave here the source of the article from which I have taken the `dnsmasq` configuration. [Resolve DNS through Tor](https://tuxdiary.com/2015/11/16/resolve-dns-tor/)

Interestingly enough, as a complementary/alternative approach, the strategy used by [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) for handling UDP DNS requests is giving an invalid answer to any UDP DNS request via `dnstc` to force the operation of DNS via TCP, and thus facilitate the proxying of DNS via Tor.

See also [Visiting darknet/ Tor sites with Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361608/trying-to-use-firefox-to-access-darknet-tor-sites/361609)

Comment: To whoever tried to edit `AutomapHostsOnResolve 1` near to `DNSPort`, if you come back here and explain, I might add it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will stay as it is if you are using secure browser like Tor, it will always leak the DNS. USE Open VPN behind the Tor...

Comment: IMHO using the `dnscrypt` service as I describe in my answer will be more anonymous than using a VPN from your Tor connection.

Comment: @Finn Joe Using a VPN is just as insecure as using ISP default DNS as far as metadata is concerned. So the suggestion is a useless one.