# How to set use tor DNS as the default DNS?

Tags: dns, proxy, dnsmasq, tor, bind9

I want to have all DNS queries passing through tor.

**How to set my default DNS to go through tor?**

In other word I want to use the IP given by `tor-resolve google.com` instead of `dig google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed. Many modern linux systems overwrite your /etc/resolv.conf automatically (resolvconf for example), and several run their own local caching dns (nscd for example). Without knowing what you are on and what is running, suggestions may fail.

However, here are two places to start:

[Tor at Stackexchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests)

[Configure Resolv.conf for Tor](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Tor_enforcement/DNS/)

EDIT: also see the response by j1088099-mvrht below.

Comment: Please see this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327432/resolving-dns-via-tor?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327432/resolving-dns-via-tor?rq=1).

For short, add `DNSPort 9053` to the `torrc` and

```
server=127.0.0.1#9053
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`