# Visiting darknet/ Tor sites with Firefox

Tags: osx, freebsd, firefox

Instead of using the Tor bundle, I have done the full routing for Tor in my Linux router ; including DNS as in [resolving DNS via Tor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327432/resolving-dns-via-tor)

I can pretty well open `.onion` sites using `lynx` or `wget`.

However when using Firefox either in my FreeBSD or MacOS machines it says `Site not found`. What is happening?

P.S. I am aware of the security implications. This question is more concerned why a plain Firefox browser is not able to open such an address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays for security reasons, the Firefox DNS resolver blocks names ending up with the domain `.onion` by default.

You have to perform the following steps:

- Open `about:config`;
- It will then complain about "This might void your warranty!" (duh?), you click "I accept the risk"
- Then in the search field above your write `onion`; the keyword `network.dns.blockDotOnion` will appear;
- Double click on that line, the  (boolean) `Value` field with change from `true` to `false`

Presto, your firefox can now open `.onion` sites.

According to [this](http://www.trishtech.com/2016/03/block-tor-onion-sites-in-firefox-browser/) page, this new setting has been added in newer versions of Firefox (starting from the version 45.0).

[image: firefox]