# OpenVPN - How to debug DNS leaks

Tags: dns, openvpn, vpn

I'm using minimal Antergos linux with i3wm, with all packages being up to date and the laptop rebooted. Using Firefox as a browser, I'm experiencing DNS leaks when visiting websites such as ipleaks.net, https://www.dnsleaktest.com or https://browserleaks.com/ip.

The VPN is set up with the nm-applet using an ovpn file provided by my VPN provider. I'm have used the same ovpn files on a KDE bells-and-whistle distro, and have not experienced any DNS leaks.

My `/etc/resolve.conf` when connected to the VPN:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I have disabled WebRTC in Firefox by toggling `media.peerconnection.enabled` to false.

How can I find out what the cause of my DNS leak is and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327432/resolving-dns-via-tor

Answer (score 2):

It was a `systemd-resolved` issue; see [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7182). In order to have all traffic being pushed through the VPN, you need to install the `update-systemd-resolved` script and add `dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .` to the ovpn file.

I'm stunned that this is not seen as a serious issue with the default settings by the systemd-resolved crew...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your routing table:

```
ip route
```

I expect you have an entry for `192.168.1.0/24` to go out your local interface, as your nameserver is in that subnet the `DNS` traffic is not being routed down the VPN tunnel.

You could change your nameserver to a public one, like google: `8.8.8.8`, your `DNS` traffic should then be routed down your VPN tunnel rather than using your local nameserver.

Comment: I do have that entry. Is there another way than choosing a puclic DNS server?

Comment: @pandita Other than choosing a Public DNS server you could take a page out of my book and use a local `bind9` or similar DNS server instance as a recursive resolver, and set it to use a Public DNS server as its 'forwarder' destination.  This does, however, require you to alter your local system so that all DNS requests route *through* this local resolver.  You would also have to configure your firewall to block external DNS requests to the system from other non-local systems if you haven't already done that, though, because you don't want others to use your computer as a DNS server.

Comment: (note that the solution in my other comment is technically OS-agnostic so long as you have a Linux system that can run `bind9` or similar; it does, however, have its own caveats and configuration headaches depending on what networking / DNS management software is in use on your system)

Comment: So I tried changing the DNS nameserver using `dnsmasq` to `8.8.8.8`, yet the entry still shows up, and the leak prevails... I set `no-resolv` and `no-poll` in `dnsmasq.conf`. `journalctl -u dnsmasq` confirms that `8.8.8.8#53` is used as the nameserver... any ideas for further debugging?

Comment: I also change my DNS nameserver directly on my router. This time browserleaks only sees the google DNS server, however it is still not routed via my VPN...